# Django RadioSelect Widget not iterating correctly

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am attempting to iterate over a ChoiceField and display radio buttons separately in my template. However when i use the standard approach of running the field through a for loop my non of the attributes render anything.

Here is a snippet from my form

```
class ResponseForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (('1', 'First',), ('2', 'Second',))
    suggestions = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=CHOICES)
```

Snippet from the template

```
{% for radio in response_form.suggestions %}
    {{ radio.id_for_label }} {{ radio.choice_label }} {{ radio.tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is how the radio variable looks in the debugger during the for loop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyCE6.png

We are running Django 1.5, so this should be supported. Haven't been able to work this one out from the docs/other answers and I'm not sure what would interfere with this.

**Edit:**

The default RadioSelect widget was being overridden by the floppyforms module, which doesn't seem to be iterable in this way (which would make sense).

Comment: I've just realised we are using floppyforms which is replacing the default widget, this seems like a likely suspect for the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am working without floppyform, and the same codes rendered correctly in my project. Suggest you focusing on the overriding of `RadioSelect`, maybe you can use `widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=CustomRenderer)` to realize the same function, and keep the default RadioSelect Widget.